# Trying to search for a identification number and password from a file

Tags: c, visual-c++

i would like to search the file for a password and identification number. i wrote them perfectly to the file but whenever i tried to search for them its nothing working whenever i do run/compile the code nothing pop up on the screen i dont know whats wrong. i would really appreciate some help.

```
void EgleEnergyEmployee()
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int Employ_Iden,i;
    char Employ_Name[30],Password[30],Username[30],Job_Type[30];

    fp = fopen("Employee Data.txt","w");
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File is not available\n");
    }
    else
        {
            printf("Please enter identification number\n");
            scanf("%d", &Employ_Iden);
            printf("Please enter your name\n");
            scanf("%s", Employ_Name);
            printf("Please enter your Job Title\n");
            scanf("%s", Job_Type);
            printf("Please enter your username\n");
            scanf("%s", Username);
            printf("Please enter password\n");
            scanf("%s", Password);
            while (!feof(stdin))
            {
                fprintf(fp,"Employee Identification Numbers %10d    Employee Name %10s    Username %10s   Password %10s\n",Employ_Iden,Employ_Name,Job_Type,Username,Password);
                printf("Please enter identification number\n");
                scanf("%d", &Employ_Iden);
                printf("Please enter your name\n");
                scanf("%s", Employ_Name);
                printf("Please enter your Job Title\n");
                scanf("%s", Job_Type);
                printf("Please enter your username\n");
                scanf("%s", Username);
                printf("Please enter password\n");
                scanf("%s", Password);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);

    int SearchEmployee(int EmployID)
    {
        FILE *fp = NULL;
        bool NotFound = 1;
        int Employ_Iden,i;
        char Employ_Name[30],Password[30],Username[30],Job_Title[30];

        fp = fopen("Employee Data.txt","r");
        if (fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("File is not available\n");
        }
        else
            {
                rewind(fp);
                while (!feof(fp)&& NotFound)
                {
                  fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %s",&Employ_Iden,Employ_Name,Password,Username);
                  if (Employ_Iden == EmployID)
                   {

                        printf("%d \t %s \t %s \t %s",Employ_Iden,Employ_Name,Password,Username);
                        NotFound = 0;
                   }
                   else
                        {
                             NotFound = 1;
                             //printf("Not Found\n");
                        }
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
    int main()
     {
              int result,Employ;

              printf("Please enter your employee identification number\n");
              scanf("%d", &Employ);
              result = SearchEmployee(Employ);
              if (result == Employ)
              {
                   printf("Its here");
              }
              else
              {
                   printf("Its not here");
              }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138795/discussion-on-question-by-a-tait-trying-to-search-for-a-identification-number-an).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to write the code:

1. code cleanly compiles
2. code is very readable'
3. all the comments in the question are addressed

and now the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fread(), fwrite(), scanf(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


#define MAX_LEN 30

struct data
{
    int Employ_Iden;
    char Employ_Name[ MAX_LEN ];
    char Password[ MAX_LEN ];
    char Username[ MAX_LEN ];
    char Job_Type[ MAX_LEN ];
};


void EgleEnergyEmployee( void );
int SearchEmployee(int EmployID);


void EgleEnergyEmployee( void )
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    struct data Employee;

    fp = fopen("Employee Data.txt","a");
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        perror("File is not available\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Please enter identification number or -1 to stop\n");
        if( 1 != scanf("%d", &Employee.Employ_Iden) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for employee ID failed" );
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        if( -1 == Employee.Employ_Iden )
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("Please enter your name\n");
        if( 1 != scanf("%29s", Employee.Employ_Name) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for employee name failed" );
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        printf("Please enter your Job Title\n");
        if( 1 != scanf("%29s", Employee.Job_Type) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for employee job type failed" );
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        printf("Please enter your username\n");
        if( 1 != scanf("%29s", Employee.Username) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for employee user name failed" );
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        printf("Please enter password\n");
        if( 1 != scanf("%29s", Employee.Password) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for employee password failed" );
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        if( 1 != fwrite( &Employee, sizeof( Employee ), 1, fp ) )
        {
            perror( "fwrite for new employee record failed" );
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    } // end while

    fclose(fp);
} // end function: EgleEnergyEmployee


int SearchEmployee(int EmployID)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    struct data Employee;

    fp = fopen("Employee Data.txt","r");
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        perror("File is not available\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    while(  1 == fread(&Employee, sizeof( Employee ), 1, fp ) )
    {
       if (Employee.Employ_Iden == EmployID)
       {
            printf("%d \t %s \t %s \t %s",
                Employee.Employ_Iden,
                Employee.Employ_Name,
                Employee.Password,
                Employee.Username);
            return EmployID; // indicate search successful
            break;
       }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;  // indicate search failed
} // end function: SearchEmployee


int main( void )
{
    int result;
    int Employ;

    printf("Please enter your employee identification number\n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &Employ) )
    {
      perror( "scanf for your employee number failed" );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    result = SearchEmployee(Employ);

    if (result == Employ)
    {
       printf("Its here");
    }

    else
    {
       printf("Its not here");
    }
}
```

Note: the function: `EgleEnergyEmployee()` is still not being called